# Which Query of JOIN with DISTINCT & JOIN with Subquery has better Performance?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

In the following two queries: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/081f9e/11

```
#1ST QUERY
SELECT a.id,
       g.names as gamma,
       o.names as omega
FROM alpha a
     JOIN (SELECT ao.alpha_id,
               GROUP_CONCAT(o.name) AS names
           FROM alpha_omega ao
               JOIN omega o on o.id = ao.omega_id
           GROUP BY ao.alpha_id ) o ON o.alpha_id = a.id
     JOIN (SELECT ag.alpha_id,
               GROUP_CONCAT(g.name) AS names
           FROM alpha_gamma ag
               JOIN gamma g on g.id = ag.gamma_id
           GROUP BY ag.alpha_id ) g ON g.alpha_id = a.id
WHERE a.id = 1;


#2ND QUERY
SELECT a.id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.name) AS gamma, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT o.name) AS omega 
FROM alpha a
     JOIN alpha_omega ao ON ao.alpha_id = a.id 
     JOIN omega o ON o.id = ao.omega_id 

     JOIN alpha_gamma ag ON ag.alpha_id = a.id 
     JOIN gamma g ON g.id = ag.gamma_id
WHERE a.id = 1
GROUP BY a.id;
```

Which one of them is better to be used to achieve the optimal performance and efficiency?

The First one uses **JOIN with SubQueries** while the Second one uses **JOIN with DISTINCT**, In the **First** one I get exactly **8 values** out from **gamma & omega columns**,

But in the Second one, I get duplicated values up to the **double**, Which makes me get **16 value**, Then I use `DISTINCT` to make it **8 values**

Keeping in mind that I've set the correct `INDEX`es to achieve the maximum speed from `INDEX`.

Which is better to be used on the long-term exactly?

Let's say I have 50,000 record in each Table, And the Query is executed 20,000 time per Sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is good, when you select a larger range, the engine should no longer treat the "subqueries" as such, but run them independantly, and join the results.